# How to find and take specific word from text file in C?

Tags: c, function

The function is big but I have take some code from that function and I have a question that how to find that specific name from text file? I am not sure.

```
for (option = 1; option <= sizeof(listing)/sizeof(char *); ++option)
   printf("%d. Your %s:\n", option, listing[option-1]); 

fputs("Select your choice to update: ", stdout);

if ((scanf("%d", &option) != 1) || (option < 1) || (option > sizeof(listing)/sizeof(char *))) 
{
  puts("invalid choice");
  fclose(fr3);
  return -1;
}

int one_by_one;
printf("Enter new name to update: ");
scanf("%s",&updated_name);

for (one_by_one=0; file_text[one_by_one] != '\0'; one_by_one++)
{
    while(file_text[one_by_one] == updated_name)
    {
        one_by_one++;
        if (one_by_one == strlen(updated_name))
        {
            found=1;
            printf("It is found: \n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to search and update any name, you should take a line from source file using `fgets()` and store in a temporary `char` array. Then you can use string function like `strstr()` function to find the name in that line, if found replace it otherwise `continue`.

You can refer to this [link](https://codeforwin.org/2018/02/c-program-find-and-replace-a-word-in-file.html) for some help.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
scanf("%s",&updated_name);
```

This will allow the user to overrun the buffer: `updated_name`.   Suggest including a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of `updated_name[]` because `%s` always appends a NUL byte to the input.  This will avoid a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.

regarding:

```
while(file_text[one_by_one] == updated_name)
```

strings cannot be compared with a C operator.  Suggest using `strcmp()`.  Also, this is comparing a string to a single character, which does not work.

to find a sub string in a string, strongly suggest using: `strstr()`