# How to seek and replace data/line in opened file

Tags: c, file

Hi guys I'm new to files. I have to find a specific data (KJadid.Tedad) and replace some other integer in it. here's the code I'm using :

```
    fseek(fileKALAJADIDptr, 0, SEEK_SET);

    int mojoodi, shomare;
    scanf("%d", &shomare);
    scanf("%d", &mojoodi); 

    int i = 0;
    while (fread(&KJadid, sizeof(struct KalaJadid), 1, fileKALAJADIDptr))
    {
        if (i == shomare - 1)
        {
            KJadid.Tedad = mojoodi;
            fseek(fileKALAJADIDptr, (shomare - 1) * sizeof(struct KalaJadid), SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&KJadid, sizeof(struct KalaJadid), 1, fileKALAJADIDptr);
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fileKALAJADIDptr);
```

with fseek I go to the beginning of the file then get shomare & mojoodi ("shomare" is the struct I want to change its data and "mojoodi" is new data) , then I read the file til I reach the struct that I want , then I use fseek to replace data where it was and use fwrite to write data into file , but when I print data (which I use this code for: )

```
int i = 0;
while (fread(&KJadid, sizeof(struct KalaJadid), 1, fileKALAJADIDptr))
{
    printf("\n\n\n\tID: %d \t %s \t Gheymat: %d \t Tedad: %d \t Emtyaz: %d \t Daste Bandi: %s \n\n\t 
    Sharh Kala: \n\n\t\t %s", i + 1, KJadid.EsmKala, KJadid.Gheimat, KJadid.Tedad, KJadid.Emtiaz, 
    KJadid.DasteBandi, KJadid.Sharh);
    i++;
}
```

it prints all data that it had before and at last prints new data (it doesn't replace anything , just adds data to the end of file)

you guys asked how I opened the file:

```
FILE* fileKALAJADIDptr = fopen(fileKALAJADID, "a+b");
if (fileKALAJADIDptr == NULL)
{
    fopen(fileKALAJADID, "w+");
}
```

**what should I do for just replacing the data and not write the whole thing at the end? please help**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find and take specific word from text file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259603/how-to-find-and-take-specific-word-from-text-file-in-c)

Comment: Check this [c-program-find-and-replace-a-word-in-file](https://codeforwin.org/2018/02/c-program-find-and-replace-a-word-in-file.html).

Comment: Show us how you open the file.

Comment: @Lucas It doesn't answer my question but thank you

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I added the opening file part

Comment: regarding: `fopen(fileKALAJADID, "w+");`  This will 'trim/truncate' the file length to 0,  Not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the file in the wrong mode:

*"When a file is opened with the "a" or "a+" access type, all write operations occur at the end of the file. The file pointer can be repositioned using fseek or rewind, **but is always moved back to the end of the file before any write operation is carried out. Thus, existing data cannot be overwritten.**"*

Open the file in mode "r+" - Opens the file for both reading and writing. (The file must exist.)